# html5 video element didnt display

Tags: html, video

I've got some stupid problem... Simple code:

```
<div id="start">
    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
        <source src="Content/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
</div>
```

on my project is not working. The video isn't displying, the path is correct... Div start has no special styling and for video is just set width and height as above.

When i checked example on http://www.w3schools.com/ everything works, when i check my browsers support for video it's all ok. And more funnier thing, that when i download the video than its downloading my proper video....

Comment: Hello. Do you mind providing the absolute link to your video in order to check if it is properly working and to be able to run a test on this side? Additionally, check if the folder named "Content" should be in uppercase for the first letter. Thank you. :)

Comment: Nope... I change the src for link: http://www.englishforkids.t15.org/movie.mp4 and it still didnt change nothing...

Comment: The video won't play this side. Maybe you need to give it the proper file permissions in order to be "read" by the "world". chmod 755 in the movie.mp4 file will be sufficient. Check it out and give it a new try. Let us know if you succeed.

Comment: argh, still nothing, even tried with chmod 777...
i hate this :(

Comment: I can see the video just after downloading. So I assume it is a server side problem. Please relax and check it out, maybe your current public_html folder or the .htaccess directives won't allow you to read these files directly from the root. Try moving the video into a folder, let's call it "videos", give the permissions to the folder and make sure the file preserves its own permissions after moving into the folder. Give a new try and check if there is something that could be stopping the video from being broadcasted.

Comment: I dropped an answer for you. Your video is working perfectly. You are experiencing a cross browser file formats issue. Check it out and don't hesitate to ask if you need further assistance. Additionally, you may wish to revert the 777 file permissions to something more secure like 755. Good luck!

Comment: i will put it into youtube's form... i think that it's something with video element support...

Comment: Well, no... it is about the file formats itself. Check it out the wiki I provided on the answer please. Youtube can also be a useful tool but I suggest you to use it for fallback only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after some testing I can see your video on Mozilla Firefox but your video won't run in Google Chrome nor Internet Explorer. The situation you are facing is based on file formats. Each web browser will require a certain file format for your video, thus you will need to encode your video in several formats in order to make the video available for a wider range of visitors, depending on their browser.

The Wikipedia explains which file formats will better fit the needs of each web browser in the **[Browser support Section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video#Browser_support)** of the HTML5 video tag.

The proper application of the `<video>` tag in your code would look like this:

```
<video poster="movie.jpg" controls>
        <source src="movie.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8.0, vorbis"'/>
        <source src="movie.ogg" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'/>
        <source src="movie.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.4D401E, mp4a.40.2"'/>
        <p>This is fallback content</p>
</video>
```

Considering that you should supply individual video files for each instance of the `sources` inside the `<video>` tag.

Remember that your fallback content can also be an image, animated gif, a flash animation or even a youtube code (properly formatted) which will result in something being shown to the user if nothing works. Don't forget to include the measurements: fixed width and height in order to the fallback media fill the whole space where the video should show.

For your transcoding procedure, I suggest you to have a look at [**This answer in the AskUbuntu site**](https://askubuntu.com/a/25532/9598) where I explain how to compress your files with ease by using the **[Mobile Media Converter by Miksoft software](http://www.miksoft.net/mobileMediaConverter.php)**.

I hope this help you but if you need further assistance don't hesitate to drop a comment.

Good luck!